# How to convert timestamp string to timestamp format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying convert a timestamp string to timestamp. I am using below method but it returns 2024-03-18T00:00 but i want in a format of this yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime
val datasettime="2024-03-18 00:00:00"
val datetime_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
println(LocalDateTime.parse(datasettime,datetime_format)) //2024-03-18T00:00
println(datetime_format.parse(datasettime)); //returns 2024-03-18T00:00
```

Comment: do you want to do this in scala or spark ?

Comment: scala. but if it can done done in spark sql, that is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `Spark` using `date_format` function.

```
val dt = spark
.sql(s"SELECT date_format('${datasettime}', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as dt").as[String].collect.head
```

```
println(dt)
2024-03-18 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code provided in your question:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val datasettime = "2024-03-18 00:00:00"
val datetime_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
println(LocalDateTime.parse(datasettime, datetime_format)) // 2024-03-18T00:00
println(datetime_format.parse(datasettime)) // returns 2024-03-18T00:00
```

To get the output in the yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format, you can slightly modify your code like this:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val datasettime = "2024-03-18 00:00:00"
val datetimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(datasettime, datetimeFormat)
val formattedTimestamp = localDateTime.format(datetimeFormat)
println(formattedTimestamp) // Output: 2024-03-18 00:00:00
```

The main difference is that this code explicitly formats the LocalDateTime object into a string in the desired format before printing it, using localDateTime.format(datetimeFormat).

Your original code directly prints the LocalDateTime or TemporalAccessor object, which results in the output 2024-03-18T00:00.

By adding the formatting step, you get the output in the yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format as you want.

---

In SQL Spark

```
// Using Spark SQL's date_format function to format the timestamp
val dt = spark
  .sql(s"SELECT date_format('${datasettime}', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as dt")
  .as[String]
  .collect
  .head

println(dt)
// Output: 2024-03-18 00:00:00
```

This approach uses Spark SQL's date_format function to directly format the timestamp string. The SQL query selects the result of date_format with the 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' format and the alias 'dt'. Then, the result is collected, and the first element is extracted using head. Finally, the formatted timestamp is printed.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.